# Hiding fields when creating node and showing them only when editing

Tags: nodes, forms

I'd need to enable editing of certain fields only when the node they're assigned to already exists. Therefore I need to disable them on node create form and enable them on node edit form.

I though I'd do it the same way as with users where you have two separate forms (user profile a user register) and therefore can use settings array on field instance (at least I believe it works this way).

```
...
'settings' => array(
   'user_register_form' => 0, 
),
...
```

The problem is you can't do it with nodes as nodes don't have separate forms for edit and create.

I know I can do it directly via altering CONTENTTYPENAME_node_form (changing the access status of the fields to false or unseting them completely when the node does not yet exist) but it doesn't seem to be the very best solution (It doesn't feel systematical to unset it on form alter hook).

BTW: I know that someone asked [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68857/exclude-fields-from-a-node-add-form-but-keep-them-on-the-node-edit-form-by-exc) but he hasn't received any answers.

Comment: There is nothing bad about using #access=false in a hook_form_alter. But avoid deleting fields using unset() because it may produces problems/php notices with other modules which implement hook_form_alter or the form validation.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Will do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly without a doubt a job for [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and quite easy to accomplish, eg, something along the lines of:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'foo_node_form':

      if ($_GET['q']=='node/add/foo') {

        // we are creating a node of type foo so do stuff to the form one way here

      } else {

        // we are editing a node of type foo so do stuff to the form another way here

      }

      break;

   // other forms here

  }

}
```